# Simple Elliptic Curve Cryptography Method

Tags: encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption, elliptic-curve

I'm working on a project in order to learn the ECC encryption algorithm & I'm implementing it in OCaml. I'm having trouble finding an answer to this question online:

Is there an asymmetric encryption algorithm method (similar to Elgamal and RSA) using ECC instead of symmetric key agreement (i.e. via ECC Diffie-Hellman)? A trivial method would be fine for our purposes.

Comment: ...what´s about Elgamal?

Comment: You can trivially construct asymmetric encryption on top of DH key exchange by generating an ephemeral sender key and using the shared key to encrypt. ECIES is a standard choice (you can simplify the key derivation if you want). I would not use ElGamal, unless you need its homomorphic properties.

Comment: Well you could indeed include ElGamal for completeness, if it is for a library, but I would heed the warning of CodesInChaos. Besides that, what's EC without DH?

Comment: ElGamal is just using the shared Diffie-Hellman key as a one-time-pad without authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There is Elliptic Curve Elgamal, for example, and several other asymmetric cryptosystems using Elliptic Curves.

Elgamal and Diffie-Hellman are both based on the "discrete logarithm problem": given integers {1, 2, ... , p-1}, a generator g, it's easy to compute g^k. However, given some element x in {1,2, ... ,p-1}, it's (supposedly) hard to find k such that g^k=x.

For Elliptic curves, we have something similar: given am elliptic curve, and a generator point P, it's easy to multiply a point by an integer k. But we believe that, given a point Q, it's hard to find k such that Q=kP.

This question has been asked in [crypto.stackexchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9987/elgamal-with-elliptic-curves).

There is also a nice description of Elliptic Curve Cryptography (including ECElgamal) [by Martin Leslie of U. of Arizona](http://math.arizona.edu/~mleslie/files/ecc.pdf).

Some comments, in case you are going to implement Elgamal:

- Elgamal is homomorphic, as someone already mentioned in the comments. If you don't want the homomorphic property, use some blinding technique.
- Elgamal will make the encrypted text quite larger than the plain text.
- "Textbook implementation" of cryptographic methods are usually flawed. See the book by Wenbo Mao,  [*Modern Cryptography: Theory and Practice*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013288741X).